# What am I missing when getting nouns from sentence and reversed sentence using nltk?

Tags: python, nltk

I Have a `is_noun` definition using `nltk`:

```
is_noun = lambda pos: pos == 'NN' or pos == 'NNP' or pos == 'NNS' or pos == 'NNPS'
```

then I have this in a function:

```
def test(text):
    tokenized = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    nouns = [word for (word, pos) in nltk.pos_tag(tokenized) if is_noun(pos)]  
    print ('Nouns:', nouns)
    return nouns
```

then I call the function:

```
test('When will this long and tedious journey ever end? Like all good')
```

and get:

```
Nouns: ['journey']
```

then call same function but with reversed sentence and get:

```
test('good all Like end? ever journey tedious and long this will When')
```

results:

```
  Nouns: ['end']
```

I am expecting to get same amount of nouns but that is not the case. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess `POS tagging` expects sentence to be grammatically correct but your 2nd sentence if far from it. Thus you're getting different results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Summary: GIGO (Garbage In => Garbage Out).

As the comment suggests, word order matters.  English is rife with words that can act as multiple parts of speech, depending on placement within a phrase.  Consider:

```
You can cage a swallow.
You cannot swallow a cage.
```

In the second text you present, you do not have a legal sentence by any means.  The best the English parser can determine is that "end" may be the direct object of the verb "like", and is therefore a noun in this case.  Similarly, "journey" appears to be the main verb of the second sequence of words.